# how to dynamically access template reference variables (symbol: #) defined in the angular.html

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, angular8, disabled-input

I am not able to access  template reference variables #interface if this.activeTab = 'interface';

```
//  parent.html
<button type="button" [disabled]="activeTab.revertDisabled"></button>
<interface-settings #interface></interface-settings>
<car #car></car>

// parent.ts
 this.activeTab = 'interface';

//child.ts (interface-settings.ts)
 this.revertDisabled = true;
```

but if I change it to the following, then it is able to access #interface.

```
 <button type="button" [disabled]="interface.revertDisabled"></button>
```

Is there a way that I can dynamically access the values for 'this.activeTab'?

I have tried the following but doesn't work

```
 <button type="button" [disabled]="[activeTab].revertDisabled"></button>
```

Comment: What is `this.activeTab.revertDisabled`? you assigned 'interface' which is a string.

Comment: I would like this.activeTab to be dynamic value in ts file. Is there a way that I can pass the string value as a reference to the #?

Comment: Can you please describe what are you trying to achieve? It's a bit hard to answer without context here.

Comment: when user switch tabs, it will access the variable - revertDisabled of the active/selected tabs. For example, if I switch to 'interface' tab, this.activeTab = 'interface', the button will access revertDisabled value of the 'interface' component. If switch to 'car' tab, this.activeTab=''car', and the button will access revertDisabled value of the 'car' component. The value of .'this.activeTab' changes according to the selected tabs.

Comment: However I am not able to pass a string value to the template reference variable. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

How a about using getter

```
get revertDisabled(){
   return yourActivetabl.get.somehow.your.value;

}
```

and

```
<button type="button" [disabled]="revertDisabled"></button>
```

If you need to get instance of of interface component as well, use

```
@ViewChildren("interface") //this is the #innterface value
instances:QueryList(InterfaceClass);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the `activeTab` as reference because `activeTab` is a string. Instead you should use brackets notation as you did, so that you can reference to the class member that it's name is the value of `activeTab`.

Add `this` to before the brackets:

```
<button type="button" [disabled]="this[activeTab].revertDisabled"></button>
```

Live example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-o1mxe1